# CORE_PCM_MODULE is not loaded when I start FreeSwitch service

Tags: sip, freeswitch

I'm installing freeswitch 1.6.19
when I use "show codecs" to see the codecs loaded

CORE_PCM_MODULE, CORE_SPEEX_MODULE, CORE_VPX_MODULE are not loaded

```
> show codecs
codec,ADPCM (IMA),mod_spandsp
codec,AMR,mod_amr
codec,B64 (STANDARD),mod_b64
codec,G.722,mod_spandsp
codec,G.723.1 6.3k,mod_g723_1
codec,G.726 16k,mod_spandsp
codec,G.726 16k (AAL2),mod_spandsp
codec,G.726 24k,mod_spandsp
codec,G.726 24k (AAL2),mod_spandsp
codec,G.726 32k,mod_spandsp
codec,G.726 32k (AAL2),mod_spandsp
codec,G.726 40k,mod_spandsp
codec,G.726 40k (AAL2),mod_spandsp
codec,G.729,mod_g729
codec,GSM,mod_spandsp
codec,H.261 Video (passthru),mod_h26x
codec,H.263 Video (passthru),mod_h26x
codec,H.263+ Video (passthru),mod_h26x
codec,H.263++ Video (passthru),mod_h26x
codec,H.264 Video (passthru),mod_h26x
codec,H263 Video,mod_av
codec,H263+ Video,mod_av
codec,H264 Video,mod_av
codec,LPC-10,mod_spandsp
codec,OPUS (STANDARD),mod_opus
codec,iLBC,mod_ilbc

26 total.
```

CORE_PCM_MODULE, CORE_SPEEX_MODULE, CORE_VPX_MODULE are loaded when I use the commands in fs_cli

```
> reload CORE_PCM_MODULE
> reload CORE_SPEEX_MODULE
> reload CORE_VPX_MODULE
```

But the three modules are gone when I restart freeswitch service.

How to make these CORE modules loaded when I start freeswitch service?

The audio codec transcoding is not working properly either. I don't know if the problem is related to the CORE_MODULE loading.

Answer (score 0):

I tried modified freeswitch-1.6.19/src/switch_loadable_module.c. And it solved this problem.
But I don't know if the modification damaged other module loading process.

This issue can also be found in freeswitch jira: https://freeswitch.org/jira/browse/FS-9102

The patch file is attched below

```
--- switch_loadable_module.c    2017-07-13 20:07:30.000000000 +0800
+++ freeswitch-1.6.19/src/switch_loadable_module.c  2017-09-29 17:23:10.000000000 +0800
@@ -1875,15 +1875,6 @@

    if (!autoload) return SWITCH_STATUS_SUCCESS;

-   switch_loadable_module_load_module("", "CORE_SOFTTIMER_MODULE", SWITCH_FALSE, &err);
-   switch_loadable_module_load_module("", "CORE_PCM_MODULE", SWITCH_FALSE, &err);
-   switch_loadable_module_load_module("", "CORE_SPEEX_MODULE", SWITCH_FALSE, &err);
-#ifdef SWITCH_HAVE_YUV
-#ifdef SWITCH_HAVE_VPX
-   switch_loadable_module_load_module("", "CORE_VPX_MODULE", SWITCH_FALSE, &err);
-#endif
-#endif
-
    if ((xml = switch_xml_open_cfg(cf, &cfg, NULL))) {
        switch_xml_t mods, ld;
        if ((mods = switch_xml_child(cfg, "modules"))) {
@@ -1980,6 +1971,15 @@
        apr_dir_close(module_dir_handle);
    }

+   switch_loadable_module_load_module("", "CORE_SOFTTIMER_MODULE", SWITCH_FALSE, &err);
+   switch_loadable_module_load_module("", "CORE_PCM_MODULE", SWITCH_FALSE, &err);
+   switch_loadable_module_load_module("", "CORE_SPEEX_MODULE", SWITCH_FALSE, &err);
+#ifdef SWITCH_HAVE_YUV
+#ifdef SWITCH_HAVE_VPX
+   switch_loadable_module_load_module("", "CORE_VPX_MODULE", SWITCH_FALSE, &err);
+#endif
+#endif
+
    switch_loadable_module_runtime();

    memset(&chat_globals, 0, sizeof(chat_globals));
```